# change class in fragment throw activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have three fragments, and one activity. 
i have put the two fragments side by side in the activity and i would like when click on the first fragment, to change it to the third one.

activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainPage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.user1.lotus.MainMenu" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/side_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.user1.lotus.SideBar" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

now i would like to change `class="com.example.user1.lotus.MainMenu"`
to `class="com.example.user1.lotus.Starter"` through my activity

Is this possible?

in activity

```
public void onFragmentInteraction(String s){
          switch (s){
                case "menu":
                    break;
                case "starters":
                    break;
                case "mainDish":
                    MainDish newFragment = new MainDish();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    transaction.replace(R.id.mainPage, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    transaction.commit();
```

and in the fragment

```
 btnMainDish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction("mainDish");
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you click on first fragment, you should get the third fragment is it? then it is definitely possible.

Comment: yes thats exactly. i have a button on the first and by clicking it, it gets replaced by the third one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this in the onClick listener method of the button your fragment will get replaced by the third fragment:

```
ThirdFragment newFragment = new ThirdFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.layout_replace, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for voting. If this has helped you, then please accept it as an answer also.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user1.lotus.first_fragm cannot be cast to com.example.user1.lotus.third_fragm
 it gives me these error

Comment: i have added it above

Comment: sorry, i have forgot to add this lines, as i was trying to find the error at the same time ` MainMenu fragment = (MainMenu) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainPage);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {` added before the switch... the error is in this line, and when i erase it, nothing happens.. no errors, but no replacement either.

Comment: check my edit in the answer, sorry its ThirdFragment newFragment = new ThirdFragment(), after changing this, let me know whether its working?

Comment: yes this is what i have done if you check my code in switch above.

Comment: Do one thing first add the replace method directly in onClick method of button instead of calling switch, initially do this to check whether replace is working.

Comment: Still nothing happens

Comment: you are not giving the id of the layout properly hence replace is not happening, R.id.mainPage is the id of the fragment, it should not be the id of fragment, it should be id of the layout such as linear or relative layout in which you are trying to replace the fragment.

Comment: You are having separate xml files for fragments right? why are you calling them here? in main xml

Comment: just visit this link, every thing will be clear for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDNoJc7azMs&index=17&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo

Comment: Welcome. If that solves your problem, then please accept it as an answer here. Thank you.

Comment: your correction works perfectly! i just restarted android studio and now it works! thank you very much!

Comment: Cool :) Nice its working. Happy coding. Thanks for accepting it as an answer.